# Putting forum data into separate arrays

Tags: javascript

```
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Load Location " + (i) + " (m): "));
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "loadLocation" + i;
input.id = "loadLocation" + i;
container.appendChild(input);

container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Load Magnitude " + (i) + " (N): "));
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";    
input.name = "loadMagnitude" + i;
input.id = "loadMagnitude" + i;
container.appendChild(input);
```

I'm dynamically generating two different types of forum elements, the location of  loads and the magnitude of loads. After getting the input I want to use JavaScript to put each set of data into their respective arrays to end up with something like:

```
loadLocation [] = [loadLocation1, loadLocation2, ...]
loadMagnitude[] = [loadMagnitude1, loadMagnitude2, ...]
```

Is there any way to loop thorough form elements based on a partial match of id/name? If not is there a simpler way I could set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the children property to obtain any elements that are within the form. As for entering the data into the correct array, you can use objects for that.

I'm assuming the form elements have an id or name that represent what kind of data it is receiving, thus using objects you can assign the id as a property and an empty array as its value:

```
var loadDataArrays={
  "location":[],
  "magnitude":[]
};

function assignData(formID){
  var form=document.getElementById(formID);
  var formChildren=form.children;
  //Loop through child elements of form element (inputs)
  for(var i in formChildren){
    var child=formChildren[i];
    //Using the form id, you can push the data of its child elements to the correct array
    loadDataArrays[formID].push(child.id);
  }
}
```

To access the array you can simply do something like:

```
var locationData=loadDataArrays["location"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I might have figured it out. Add a class for each category and getElementsByClass. I believe that will return an array in the order that the elements were created.